# problems when using getchar() repeatedly in C

Tags: c, getchar

My code:

```
#include "stdio.h"
main() {
    char a,b;
    a=getchar();
    b=getchar();

    putchar(a);
    putchar('\n');
    putchar(b);
}
```

getchar() requires user to enter a character and then press enter to assign it to the variable. I expected the program letting me enter the character twice, each time finished by pressing enter. But I was only able to enter one character string and the program will automatically read the first two characters and assign them to each variable. 
What's the problem?

Comment: the problem is that you type character + enter. The first `getchar()` reads the character, the second the newline. Many similar questions here, btw.

Comment: Each time you hit ENTER you do enter a character (`\n`). So you are actually entering 2 chars at a time.

Comment: Aside: `#include"stdio.h" main() { char a,b; ...` should be `#include <stdio.h> int main(void) { int a,b; ...`

Comment: `getchar()` reads from the input buffer when `Enter` is pressed. So if you type `a` then `b` then `Enter`, the output will be `a` and `b`.

Answer (score -1):

> getchar() requires user to enter a character and then press enter to assign it to the variable.

No. `getchar()` accepts single character as input . Even enter `\n` is considered as a single character to `getchar()`.
So when you enter a character it would be the input for first `getchar()` and enter `'\n'` will be the input for second `getchar()`.

Ex:

When you press `a` it would be read by first `getchar()`, after which if u hit enter `'\n'` it would be considered as input for second `getchar()`.